# py2exe windows service problem

Tags: python, windows-services, py2exe

I have successfully converted my python project to a service.  When using the usual options of install and start/stop, everything works correctly.  However, I wish to compile the project using py2exe, which seems to work correctly until you install the EXE as a service and try and run it.

You get the following error message:

- Starting service CherryPyService
- Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

My compile python file (which links to the main project) is as follows:

- from distutils.core import setup
- import py2exe
- setup(console=['webserver.py'])

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You setup.py file should contain

```
setup(service=["webserver.py"])
```

as shown in the ["old" py2exe docs](http://www.py2exe.org/old/)

Answer (score 1):

You will find an example in the py2exe package, look in site-packages\py2exe\samples\advanced.